# Returning null instead of a JSX when looping through arrays in react using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am looping through an array of objects in react using `array.map`. The array takes the form:

```js
const seasons = [
             {air_date: null, episode_count: 6},
             {air_date: "2020-02-02", episode_count: 6}
           ]
```

I am looping through the array using `seasons.map`, returning JSX if `air_date` is not `null` and `null` otherwise.

```js
 seasons.map((season, index) => {
      if(season.air_date){
         return <span key = {season.id}> {season.episode_count} </span>
     }else{
        return null; // Is this recommended?
    }  
})
```

I have never seen anyone do this (returning `null` instead of `JSX`). Is it recommended in react? I don't want to use a `for` loop.

Comment: How come you didn't see that? It's the most common way to map an array in jsx.

Comment: I have ever seen `map` being used to loop through arrays. What i have never seen is `null` being returned instead of `JSX`.

Comment: Because there are other options. Probably this is why you don't see something like this. A logical `&&` is necessary for your needs for example. You don't even need to use an `if/else` statement like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is recommended.

If you have a conditional or optional component then returning `null` to mean "no component" or "no JSX" is the way to go.

In addition, as @k-wasilweski says, using a `.map` to convert an array into a series of components is standard practice in React.

If you don't like the idea of returning nulls, you could always add a `.filter(c => c !== null)` at the end, but it's really unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Thats quite okay, but in React its more common to do it using the ternary operator:

```
seasons.map((season, index) =>
  season.air_date ? <span key={season.id}> {season.episode_count} </span> : null
);
```

And like @devserkan mentioned in the comment below, you can even just do:

```
seasons.map((season, index) =>
  season.air_date && <span key={season.id}> {season.episode_count} </span>
);
```

Comment: Not even a `ternary` is needed here. `&&` also works fine.

Comment: true I added your suggestion to the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I know about `&&` and `ternary` operator. I chose `if else` because of the many lines of `JSX` i am returning. Use of `if else`in this case makes the code more readable compared to  `&&` and `ternary` operator. The example is a simplified version of what i was trying to do.

Comment: no, thats not what I mean't, the span should only render when season.air_date is not null